# how does std::string manages this trick?

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference, stdstring, pass-by-const-reference

i just wrote a function:

```
void doSomeStuffWithTheString(const std::string& value) {
...
std::string v = value;
std::cout << value.c_str();
...
}
```

but then i call this with

```
doSomeStuffWithTheString("foo");
```

and it works. So i would have thought that this to work (a const char* to initialise a implicit instance of std::string) the value would have to be passed by value, but in this case is passed by (const) reference.

Is by any chance a implicit temporal std::string instantiated from const char* when the reference is const? if not, then how this possibly work?

**EDIT**

what happens if the function is overloaded with

```
void doSomeStuffWithTheString(const char* value);
```

which one will choose the compiler?

Comment: You pretty much answered your own question :)

Comment: interesting, didn't know that. What does a object need to have so will have such implicit constructors happens on const-by-ref calls (and how to avoid it?)

Comment: The program is ill-formed:  `std::string = value;` is not valid and should be rejected by your compiler.

Comment: @lurscher: For how to avoid it, see the `explicit` keyword.  You can only prevent implicit conversions on classes you write, however, so I don't know if there's a way to prevent the `const char *` => `std::string` implicit conversion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `std::string` type has an implicit conversion (via constructor) from `const char*`.  This is what allows the string literal `"foo"` to convert to `std::string`.  This results in a temporary value.  In C++ it's legal to have a `const &` to a temporary value and hence this all holds together.

It's possible to replicate this trick using your own custom types in C++.

```
class Example {
public:
  Example(const char* pValue) {}
};

void Method(const Example& e) {
  ...
}

Method("foo");
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a temporary `std::string` is constructed from the string literal.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly, using `std::string` default constructor

Answer (score 0):

"the value would have to be passed by value, but in this case is passed by (const) reference."

There is a C++ feature where it is possible to pass a temporary value (in this case, a temporary `std::string` implicitly converted from the `const char *`) to an argument of const-reference (in this case, `const std::string &`) type.